# How to write/read NFC card with unsupported Ndef?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I have successfully read & write nfc card with text using `NdefRecord`. But right know, i have different nfc card. Technologies are :

- MifareClassic 1k
- NfcA
- NdefFormatable

which I'm curious now, why there's no `Ndef` in that particular card. is that meaning I can't write using `NdefRecord` and read using `NdefMessage` ?

I can't read/write right now, since I don't have keyA & keyB. but I'm building a theory here.

Thanks.

Comment: So how come there is no Ndef when you have listed NdefFormatable?

Comment: Because it's not empty card, inside have message that non-Ndef formatted. `NdefFomattable` mean I could format to Ndef but that would also need access Key. that's what I understand right know. the question is, how to read non-Ndef message?

Answer (score 2):

`NdefFormatable` means that the card can be formatted to contain `NdefMessage` and after that  will have the `Ndef` technology available. You can actually format the card and write and `NdefMessage` at the same time using [`format()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NdefFormatable.html#format%28android.nfc.NdefMessage%29).

Formatting to contain NDEF will only work when the card is in default configuration, like when it came from the factory (i.e. default key A & B for all sectors in case of a MIFARE Classic card).

Comment: I'm glad you answered this. been reading all your answers. If I want to read non-Ndef format, how to? given key A&B.

Comment: Do i have to read every sectors and blocks? because using `NdefMessage` is unavailable.

Comment: Have a look at [`MifareClassic`(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.html) how to authenticate and read the blocks.

Comment: Can I read like surface information without the key?. I'm able to get ID from `EXTRA_ID`.